# Timout between Web and WCF calls

Tags: c#, database, wcf

My question is if I make a call from my web front-end to the wcf to execute some database logic but it times out from the web front-end, does the database still continue executing the query?

Answer (score 2):

If it times out from the web front-end, then the database will still continue to execute the query.

To make it clearer if your web front-end has a timeout set to 30 seconds and your database call has a timeout set to 60 seconds, there is a high chance that your front-end will result in a timeout, but your database operation would be completed in about 45 seconds.

I have faced a similar issue in a Android app facing a timeout and the called REST service still completed the operation.